# How does one figure what the total db reads & writes are for a clear_prefix call?

Tags: storage, storagemap

We need to perform a `clear_prefix` on a StorageDoubleMap every N blocks in `on_initialize()`, and we want to make sure the WeightInfo call properly accounts for read/writes. Should we simply pass `unique` in the `MultiRemovalResults` returned, or something else?  Benchmarks generated a function with only one parameter. The `on_initialize` function touches storage only via `clear_prefix`. Genericized code:

```rs
let multi_removal_result = <DoubleMapRegistry<T>>::clear_prefix(
    key1,
    T::ConfigMaxItemsToRemove::get(),
    None,
);
T::WeightInfo::on_initialize(multi_removal_result.unique)
```

Comment: Note that `multi_removal_result.loop` should probably be taken in consideration for weight calculation (it indicates how many item where queried on the state and directly impact the size of the PoV).